# Neo4J get deeper nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have problem with the query, how to get all relationship WHERE second node has an attribute

```
CREATE (spol:Spoldzielnia { value : 'Poludnie' })
CREATE (mT:Home { value : 'Trojanska' })
CREATE (mR:Home { value : 'Renesansowa' })
CREATE (mK:Home { value : 'Kasandry' })
CREATE (pS:Person { value : 'Slawek' })
CREATE (pR:Person { value : 'Remek' })
CREATE (pW:Person { value : 'Wojtek' })
CREATE (pK:Person { value : 'Krzychu' })
CREATE (pB:Person { value : 'Bolek' })
CREATE (pC:Person { value : 'Czesław' })
CREATE (pTT:Person { value : 'Tosiek' })
CREATE (pZZ:Person { value : 'Zbychu' })
CREATE (pWW:Person { value : 'Wlodek' })
CREATE (pFF:Person { value : 'Franko' })
CREATE (pMM:Person { value : 'Mietek' })
CREATE (i01:Item { value : 'telefon'})
CREATE (i02:Item { value : 'komputer'})
CREATE (i03:Item { value : 'laptop'})
CREATE (i04:Item { value : 'telefon'})
CREATE (i05:Item { value : 'komputer'})
CREATE (i06:Item { value : 'laptop'})
CREATE (mT)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (mR)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (mK)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (pS)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pR)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pW)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pK)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pB)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pC)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pTT)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pZZ)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pWW)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pFF)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pMM)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (i01)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i02)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i03)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i04)-[:HAS]->(pR)
CREATE (i05)-[:HAS]->(pR)
CREATE (i06)-[:HAS]->(pR)
```

I create something like this

```
MATCH (sp:Spoldzielnia)<-[r:HAS]-(h:Home)<--(x) WHERE h.value = 'Trojanska' return *
```

but does not give me a deeper nodes like: telefon, komputer, laptop related to the person

---

example 2:

```
CREATE (spol:Spoldzielnia { value : 'Poludnie' })
CREATE (mT:Home { value : 'Trojanska' })
CREATE (mR:Home { value : 'Renesansowa' })
CREATE (mK:Home { value : 'Kasandry' })
CREATE (pS:Person { value : 'Slawek' })
CREATE (pR:Person { value : 'Remek' })
CREATE (pW:Person { value : 'Wojtek' })
CREATE (pK:Person { value : 'Krzychu' })
CREATE (pB:Person { value : 'Bolek' })
CREATE (pC:Person { value : 'Czesław' })
CREATE (pTT:Person { value : 'Tosiek' })
CREATE (pZZ:Person { value : 'Zbychu' })
CREATE (pWW:Person { value : 'Wlodek' })
CREATE (pFF:Person { value : 'Franko' })
CREATE (pMM:Person { value : 'Mietek' })
CREATE (i01:Item { value : 'telefon'})
CREATE (i02:Item { value : 'komputer'})
CREATE (i03:Item { value : 'laptop'})
CREATE (i04:Item { value : 'telefon'})
CREATE (i05:Item { value : 'komputer'})
CREATE (i06:Item { value : 'laptop'})
CREATE (i07:hardware { value : 'modem'})
CREATE (i08:option { value : 'wifi'})
CREATE (i09:option { value : 'usb'})
CREATE (mT)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (mR)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (mK)-[:HAS]->(spol)
CREATE (pS)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pR)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pW)-[:HAS]->(mT)
CREATE (pK)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pB)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pC)-[:HAS]->(mR)
CREATE (pTT)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pZZ)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pWW)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pFF)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (pMM)-[:HAS]->(mK)
CREATE (i01)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i02)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i03)-[:HAS]->(pS)
CREATE (i04)-[:HAS]->(pR)
CREATE (i05)-[:HAS]->(pR)
CREATE (i06)-[:HAS]->(pR)
CREATE (i07)-[:HAS]->(i02)
CREATE (i08)-[:HAS]->(i07)
CREATE (i09)-[:HAS]->(i06)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your query go one hop further with relationships, like this:

```
MATCH (sp:Spoldzielnia)<-[r:HAS]-(h:Home)<--(p:Person)<-[r2:HAS]-(item:Item)
WHERE h.value = 'Trojanska' 
return item;
```

This returns:

```
+----------------------------+
| item                       |
+----------------------------+
| Node[20]{value:"laptop"}   |
| Node[19]{value:"komputer"} |
| Node[18]{value:"telefon"}  |
| Node[17]{value:"laptop"}   |
| Node[16]{value:"komputer"} |
| Node[15]{value:"telefon"}  |
+----------------------------+
```

Notice though that your `HAS` relationships between `Person` and `Item` are backwards; you have modeled that an `Item` has a `Person` when it should probably be the other way around.  :)

Comment: thanks but not exactly what I wanted because i don't know the last type node and i don't know how deep is located

example 2 clearly shows what I mean

what i wanted is a all nodes related to the 'Trojanska' and all deeper nodes no matter
how deeply they are

Comment: This `MATCH p = (sp:Spoldzielnia)<-[r:HAS]-(h:Home { value:"Trojanska" })<-[:HAS*]-(x) RETURN p` but be careful with the unbounded match. See http://console.neo4j.org/r/e9x4ep . It is an odd model though.